# UIImageView retained stronly in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have cobbled together some methods to resize images and put them into a UIScrollView for horizontal scrolling, however one of my problems is that I'm capturing strongly, and I have attempted a few options that I have read about, but all result in no images being displayed. I'm hoping one of you can help me resolve this issue so I can quit cooking so much memory when my app loads the images into the scroll view.

```
    - (void)setImage:(NSURL *)imageURL errorImage:(UIImage *)errorImage{

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:imageURL];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    UIImageView *newView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(self.x, 0, self.screenWidth, self.screenHight)];
    [self.scrollView addSubview: newView];

    self.x = (self.x + newView.frame.size.width);
    if(self.x > self.view.frame.size.width) {
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.x, self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    }

    [[newView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)]; // Remove previous that not stop

    __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init];
    activityIndicator.frame = newView.bounds;
    [activityIndicator setHidden:NO];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    activityIndicator.color = [UIColor redColor];
    [newView addSubview:activityIndicator];

    void (^removeSpinner)(void) = ^{ // Desctuctor Block
        if (activityIndicator) {
            [activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
            [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
            activityIndicator = nil;
        }
    };

    [newView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
        removeSpinner();
        // resize the resulting image for this device
        newView.image = [self imageScaleCropToSize:image];

        NSLog(@"successfully loaded image: %@", imageURL);

    } failure: ^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        removeSpinner();
        NSLog(@"failed loading [%@]: %@", imageURL, error);
    }];

}
```

Comment: This line: `[[newView subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];` does nothing.  You just created `newView`, and you haven't added any subviews to it at this point.

Comment: You create `activityIndicator`, but you never add it to a view.

Comment: Sorry let me remove that part, I'm talking about the images

Comment: Have you profiled to find out what exactly is leaking or building up in memory?

Comment: How often is this `setImage:errorImage:` method called? Each time it is called you create a new image view and download a new image. Do you ever remove any of these image views or do they just keep piling up?

Comment: I updated the example code so the spinner works... rmaddy, they just keep getting added to the UIScrollView, and never get taken off of it. I'm currently stopping it at 52 images, and allowing the user to refresh the scrollview if they choose with button.

Comment: The reason for this thread is because xcode keeps saying "Capturing 'newView' strongly in this block is likely to lead to a retain cycle" > newView.image = [self imageScaleCropToSize:image];

Comment: Use a weak reference to self to call imageScaleCropToSize